# Does Mongoose allow for Multiple Database Connections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I read that in a `nodejs` application, if we use a `mongoose` object using

> `var obj = require('mongoose')`;

then, wherever we create a new `mongoose` object (say, in another file), then the same [cached](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) copy is used throughout. In that case, how can we connect to multiple database instances of `mongoDB` in the same `nodejs` app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mongoose.createConnection](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-createConnection) to connect to a separate database, and then using the `connection` object that generates, you can define models from that database using `connection.model`.